# redirect url with primary key DJANGO

Tags: python, django

So I have a list with some recipes and I want the user to be able to click on a recipe and be redirected to a view with more details. In other words, I want every recipe to have its own url. I am trying this code as below, but it does not work, it redirects 404 side after I click on recipe.

My model:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):

  recipe_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  preparation = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
  ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)
  recipe_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default='')


  def __str__(self):
    return self.recipe_name
```

View:

```
def GenerallView(request):
    lista1 = Recipe.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'drinks/GenerallView.html', {'lista1': lista1})

def DetailView(request, pk):
    lista = get_object_or_404(Recipe, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'drinks/DetailView.html', {'lista': lista})
```

Url:

```
 path('generall_view', views.GenerallView, name='GenerallView'),
 path('detail_view/<int:pk>', views.DetailView, name='DetailView'),
```

Templates:

generall view

```
<ul>
{% for drink in lista1 %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'DetailView' pk=drink.pk %}">{{ drink.recipe_name }}</a></li>
{% empty %}
    <li>No notes yet.</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

detail view

```
<h1>{{ drink.recipe.name }}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the obbject is `drink`, not `Recipe`, so you should write this with `{% url 'DetailView drink.pk %}`, furthermore the name of your view is `DetailView`, not `detail_view`:

```
<ul>
{% for drink in lista1 %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'DetailView' drink.pk %}">{{ drink.recipe_name }}</a></li>
{% empty %}
    <li>No notes yet.</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

In the `DetailView` you passed a variable named `lista` as well, so you should render this with:

```
<h1>{{ lista.recipe_name }}</h1>
```

Comment: it did not help, i stll get 404  i have added my model to code upper. In addition i change like this <li><a href="{% url 'DetailView' pk=drink.pk %">{{ drink.recipe_name }}</a></li> but still the same

Comment: @LuiTe: are you sure that you are rendering the list with the listview? What url is generated? (What url is visted by the browser)?

Comment: so list is here http://127.0.0.1:8000/generall_view and after i click on any of recipes then i get http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%%20url%20'DetailView'%20pk=Recipe.pk%20%

Comment: @LuiTe: what is the new url?

Comment: this http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%%20url%20'DetailView'%20pk=Recipe.pk%20%

Comment: @LuiTe: then you did not refresh the server (since it is still working with the old template). It might be better to restart the server, since normally it does not see updates in the templates.

Comment: it helped! :) now every recipe gets own link, but it is just white side without any content, but in template DetailView is drink.recipe_name so it should display it. Do you know why it does not? Link is http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/detail_view/12 so it works

Comment: @LuiTe: see edit, there was a mistake in the template of the detailview as well.